# jMeter database load testing: randomizing a query predicate

Tags: sql, database, jmeter

I need to conduct a series of database performance tests using jMeter.

The database has ~32m accounts, and ~15 billion transactions.
I have configured a JDBC connection configuration and a JDBC request with a single SELECT statement and a hardcoded vAccountNum and this works fine.

SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 from transactions where account=vAccountNum

I need to measure how many results sets can be completed in five minutes for 1 session; then add sessions and tune until server resources are exhausted.
What is the best way to randomize vAccountNum so that I can get an equal distribution of accounts returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what type `vAccountNum` is the choices are in:

- Various [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) Functions like

  - [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function - to generate random number within defined range
  - [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function - returns current thread's number (1 for first thread, 2 for second, etc.)
  - [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function - a simple counter which is being incremented by 1 each time it is called
- [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) - to read pre-defined vAccountNum values from CSV file. In that case make sure that you provide enough account numbers so you won't be hammering the server with the same query which likely to be returned from cache.

Comment: Thank you. I used these functions and it all works as you described. Instead of using __Random I created a CSV file of 1m account numbers (using Pythons Random()), then used a CSV Data Set Config to read these in and assign them to a variable which I substituted into the account number. Using a test set of 50k accounts and variable numbers of threads (10,20-60) I am able to return repeatable, consistent test results. The throughput peaks at around 2400 queries per second.